# converting list like column values into multiple rows using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

CSV file: (sample1.csv)

```
Location_City, Location_State, Name, hobbies
Los Angeles,   CA,             John, "['Music', 'Running']"
Texas,         TX,             Jack, "['Swimming', 'Trekking']"
```

I want to convert hobbies column of CSV into following output

```
Location_City, Location_State, Name, hobbies
Los Angeles,   CA,             John, Music
Los Angeles,   CA,             John, Running
Texas,         TX,             Jack, Swimming
Texas,         TX,             Jack, Trekking
```

I have read csv into `dataframe` but I don't know how to convert it?

```
 data = pd.read_csv("sample1.csv") 
 df=pd.DataFrame(data)
 df
```

Comment: Can you clarify that values in hobbies column are list or string?

Comment: when it goes into datafreame it shows dtype:object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) or [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get lists from `hobbies` colum, then flatten with `chain.from_iterable` and repeat another columns:

```
a = df['hobbies'].str.findall("'(.*?)'").astype(np.object)
lens = a.str.len()

from itertools import chain

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Location_City' : df['Location_City'].values.repeat(lens),
    'Location_State' : df['Location_State'].values.repeat(lens),
    'Name' : df['Name'].values.repeat(lens),
    'hobbies' : list(chain.from_iterable(a.tolist())), 
})
```

Or create `Series`, remove first level and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.join(df.pop('hobbies').str.extractall("'(.*?)'")[0]
               .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
               .rename('hobbies'))
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
print (df1)

  Location_City Location_State  Name   hobbies
0   Los Angeles             CA  John     Music
1   Los Angeles             CA  John   Running
2         Texas             TX  Jack  Swimming
3         Texas             TX  Jack  Trekking
```

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this using `pandas.DataFrame.explode` function which was introduced in version `0.25.0` if you have same or higher version, you can use below code.
explode function reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

data = {
    'Location_City': ['Los Angeles','Texas'],
    'Location_State': ['CA','TX'],
    'Name': ['John','Jack'],
    'hobbies': ["['Music', 'Running']", "['Swimming', 'Trekking']"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Converting a string representation of a list into an actual list object

list_eval = lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
df['hobbies'] = df['hobbies'].apply(list_eval)

# Exploding the list
df = df.explode('hobbies')

print(df)

  Location_City Location_State  Name   hobbies
0   Los Angeles             CA  John     Music
0   Los Angeles             CA  John   Running
1         Texas             TX  Jack  Swimming
1         Texas             TX  Jack  Trekking
```